# Macro to remove ASCII code

Tags: excel, vba

Any idea if there is a Excel macro to remove ASCII code such as & #148; and so on.

There is a function like CLEAN for non-printable characters to do it?

Comment: please clarify your question. Do you want to remove all #148 characters from cell, entire worksheet / workbook? Please also share what have you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
Sub kleanup()
  Cells.Replace what:=Chr(148), replacement:=""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search a given cell for the char and replace it with whatever you want.

```
Dim iIndex as integer
Dim szValue as String

szValue = Range("A1").Value

iIndex = InStr(szValue, Chr(148))
If iIndex <> 0 Then
    Mid(szValue, iIndex, 1) = " "
End If

Range("A1").Value = szValue
```

Comment: Thanks in fact i would like to apply it to all ranges cells of my excel file